# C# How can I watermark a jpeg image?

Tags: c#, jpeg

Using C# how would I watermark an jpeg image that I'm reading into a memory stream and saving to a byte array?

```
using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
{
      pbPreview.Image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      photoBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look: [Watermark Creator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/watermark_creator.aspx) and [Creating a Watermarked Photograph with GDI+ for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/watermark.aspx)

A more detailed explanation here: [Build a simple watermarking utility in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/WatermarkCS05072007024947AM/WatermarkCS.aspx)