# Add date on image while uploading in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications

I am adding date and image to the database. I want to add the date as the footer to the uploaded image.

HTML for image `upload`

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Photo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <img id="DocImg" src="~/Upload/DoctorImage/doc-default.png" style="cursor: pointer;"  accesskeyclass="edtImg" width="100" height="100" />
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="Photo" accept="image/*" />
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML for `datepicker`

```
 <div class="col-6">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Joining Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @required = "required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                            .Name("JoiningDate")
                            .Value("")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", required = "true" })
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JoiningDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for Upload

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fileUpload").hide();
});

$("#DocImg").click(function () {
    $("#fileUpload").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: What does `date as the footer` mean?

Comment: found this in a thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224653/place-watermark-image-on-other-images-c-asp-net does this help?

Comment: It would make more sense to set any file metadata on the server side - especially the date.

Comment: hai mplungjan, he mean when i am uploaded image already edited and prited date of bottom of that image. which not outside the image he want inside the image

Comment: The answer Luiz Paulo posted is correct in the sense that it adds the text to the image. However it sounds like you are not actually saving that new image to the database, but the uploaded image instead

Comment: I think you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977932/c-sharp-how-can-i-watermark-a-jpeg-image)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think you need to manipulate the image in the DOM before the post
>   completes, using ajax to accomplish it

Having this in mind, all you need is to use a canvas to render the text from the datepicker inside the image.

As shown in the code -

```js
var canvasEl = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvasEl.width = $('img').width();
canvasEl.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
canvasEl.height = $('img').height();
ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
ctx.font = "36pt Verdana";

$(document).on('input','#inp',function(){
    //redraw image
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasEl.width,canvasEl.height);
    ctx.drawImage($('img').get(0), 0, 0);
    
    //refill text
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText($(this).val(),40,80); //positioning text wherever you want
});

$('button').click(function(){
    console.log(ctx.getImageData(50, 50, 100, 100));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <img style="display:none" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsEbEB4kEMHt3WJ13HpZE16hJ3iKrE8ugnErvyln7oNPDma48U" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
 <input type="text" id="inp"/>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<canvas id="canvas" />
```

Please share if it works for you?

Comment: I don't know why my answer get 1 down vote, but i think it is correct...

Comment: It doesn't matter, you gave your answer, whether it's correct or not is for the one who asked to question to decide.

Comment: @LuizPaulo Pay attention while reading the question. Although you solution (might be) perfectly valid it is not what the OP asks for - i.e. he asks for a C# based solution but you're providing a JavaScript based one. Most likely this is the reason for the down vote.

Answer (score 2):

You gonna need a reference to `System.Drawing` and play a little bit with graphics. I just authored a solution for you so it isn't bulletproof. You might wanna play around to change the colors, font, etc. as well as add exception handling.

```
public void AddWatermark(string inputhPath, string outputPath)
{
    var wm = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    using (var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(inputhPath))
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var transparentBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(164, 0, 0, 0)))
    using (var font = new Font("Calibri", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    {
        var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
        var dim = g.MeasureString(wm, font);
        var loc = new Point(bmp.Width - (int)dim.Width - 20, bmp.Height - (int)dim.Height * 2);

        g.DrawString(wm, font, transparentBrush, loc);

        bmp.Save(outputPath);
    }
}
```